# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass during assets:precompile rake while deploying with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I've got capistrano configured so that assets are compiled on production when i run deploy via capistrano. Im using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.13 with MongoDb database. Problem exists only during deployment, on both developement and production i can compile assets manually without any problem

```
desc "Update the deployed code."
task :update_code, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "cd #{current_path}; git fetch origin; git reset --hard #{branch}"
  finalize_update
  assets.precompile
end

namespace :assets do
  desc "Assets precompileing"
  task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path}; rm -rf public/assets/*"
    run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} assets:precompile"
  end
end
```

but i'm getting this error

```
executing command
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /my-app/path/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/my-app/path/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.4.5/lib/moped/protocol/reply.rb:71:in `command_failure?'
/my-app/path/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.4.5/lib/moped/node.rb:82:in `block in command'
/my-app/path/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.4.5/lib/moped/node.rb:582:in `[]'
/my-app/path/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.4.5/lib/moped/node.rb:582:in `block (3 levels) in flush'
/my-app/path/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.4.5/lib/moped/node.rb:581:in `map'
...
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 14427ms
failed: "env RAILS_ENV=production sh -c 'cd /my-app/path/current; bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production assets:precompile'"
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.
```

So it's not related to any special file in assets, i do use only pure .js and .css files.

Thought there might be some problem with multiple manifest files which i am using, but i added
    config.assets.precompile += ['another-manifest.js', 'another-manifest.css']

to application.rb and it works like charm on development and on production, if i turn off asset compilation during deploy and do it manually after deployment is finished.

I also tried leaving only one manifest file that required only self and the error was still present.

Mongoid documentation got similiar looking problem discussed in tips section
http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/tips.html

But im currently using 1.9.3 Ruby build p392 so it should be fine.

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: try adding this to your capfile ssh_options[:compression] = "none"

Comment: unfortunately, haven't made any impact

Comment: Bump. Any Resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any `asset-url` helpers like `image-url` and etc., your style files must be `.scss`.

Using scss helpers in pure css rises sprockets error during precompiling and ruins your deploy.